# How do I shutdown a thread which contains a blocking call to NetworkStream.Read

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets

I'm looking through some code which hasn't been written by myself and I'm trying to understand what is causing the application to crash.

I think that possibly it comes down to how it disposes of resources and manages threads.

A main parent thread creates a new Application layer client (TCPMonitor) which then creates another class which handles the TCP socket comms (TCPListen).  This class spawns a new thread loop that creates a new TCP socket client, a read network stream on that socket, and then calls a synchronous blocking Read().

However, if a network error connection occurs, the exception is caught in the TCPListen thread loop and an event raised back to the owning class TCPMonitor.  TCPMonitor then checks to see if it holds an active TCPListen instance and if so it calls Dispose() and sets the instance to Null.

At this point the TCPListen Read() will still be in its blocking call surely?  If that is the case, how do I ensure that calling the Dispose from the parent thread will break the child thread out of the blocking call and properly dispose of the stream and socket?

Comment: I think the `TCPListen` will still be blocked in a `Read` if there's a loop and the catch block rethrows the exception but does not exit the loop. Is that the case?

Comment: There are try/catch blocks around the close methods on the socket and stream after the read has finished, but they are not rethrown. There is also wider try/catch around most code in loop which also swallows the error. This raises an event to the parent which then disposes of the thread class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shutdown the socket for input. That will unblock the read and cause it to get an EOS indication, whatever form that takes in the API. As you are on Windows, it will also cause the other end to get a connection rest if it keeps sending. (This behaviour is platform-dependent.)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned the actual C# network API calls that your code is using, but assuming that it is one of the many "Receive" methods on the underlying Socket object, you are correct that it will block indefinitely on a bound connected socket unless a time-out is set ([ReceiveTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx)) on the Socket object.

Once set, it will return if no data is received within that time. You could then put the Receieve call in a loop on some boolean you can set externally to trigger the thread to stop.

**Update:**

Instead of blocking the thread on a synchronous Read call, you could use [DataAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable) to query the NetworkStream in a loop to see if there is anything to read instead?

Comment: The call is a simple NetworkStream.Read().  If the timeout of the read is indefinite (-1) or set to 5 mins (300000) then the thread will be hanging on the read. But if dispose is called on the thread class itself, what happens to the actual thread loop?

Comment: It will continue to block, if you ran a debug build in VS I'd expect to see it continue showing as "Running" even after the program appeared to have stopped. I am guessing a release build would tear down the thread and socket connection not particularly gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

How about using asynchronous calls (e.g. `BeginReceive`) instead of blocking calls, and have the thread wait on an object to tell it to terminate cleanly? Create something like a `ManualResetEvent` and have the thread wait on it. Signal the event from the main thread, and when the listening thread wakes up, it can close the socket.

Note that when the callback delegate is called with the data, another call to `BeginReceive` would need to be made if the thread needs to receive further data. Check the description of `BeginReceive` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxkwh6zw